# Counting Dates in a Column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in column **A**.  Some of the values are dates and some are not:

```
Cat
1234
12/25/2016
$123.45
6/10/2016
```

I want to count the number of cells in the column that contain dates of a specific format.  I am interested in counting cells for which the *CELL()* worksheet function returns *"D4"*.

I can do this with a helper column; in **B1** I enter:

```
=CELL("format",A1)
```

and then copy down.  Then in another cell:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,"D4")
```

[image]

I can also do this with a VBA UDF:

```
Public Function DateCounter(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rng
        If IsDate(r) Then DateCounter = DateCounter + 1
    Next r
End Function
```

I would like to do this without VBA and without a "helper" column.

What I have tried is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(CELL("format",A1:A5)="D4"))
```

But this always returns **0** *(either as a normal formula or an array formula)*

Comment: Are your other number ever between 41,000 and 43,000?  If not just use COUNTIFS() looking for numbers between those.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Good idea.............Any clue why the *SUMPRODUCT()* fails ??

Comment: As far as I can tell it is the CELL() formula, it does not like to be used as an array so it will only return the value of the first cell, which in this case is "G".  If you changed the first cell to a date you would get 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CELL()` does not support arrays. It is an old and well known limitation; I think there is not much you can do, except using your own logic instead of `CELL()` to check for a date format, where you check for slashes in the proper positions, valid month numbers, etc., etc.; that would be tedious but there is no other way.